# O que é convenção sobre configuração?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, convenções

Atualmente vejo que alguns *frameworks*, bibliotecas e sistemas usam o conceito de convenção sobre configuração, a partir disso levantei as seguintes questões

- O que é convenção sobre configuração?
- Quais as vantagens e desvantagens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Significa que a ferramenta é opinativa, ou seja, ela decide o que é bom para você, nas maioria dos casos. Em geral são decisões tomadas por engenheiros capacitados e experientes com aquele problema e sabem como costuma ser melhor trabalhar, porém a ferramenta deixa você mudar esse padrão já convencionado e permite uma configuração diferente do que o normal.

É uma forma de estabelecer um *default* facilitando o trabalho e induzindo os programadores mais incautos a fazerem o certo, sem impedir a flexibilidade necessária para casos fora do padrão que algo diferente pode funcionar melhor se configurado por um programador competente.

Com ele você tem que tomar menos decisões e isso é bom ou ruim. É bom porque usa o que se chama *get the things done*. É ruim porque é comum o projeto ficar simplório, fazer coisas erradas para aquele cenário.

De forma geral para o usuário da ferramenta só tem vantagens, ele já tem pronto e não tem que pensar no problema, não tem trabalho, não tem riscos de fazer errado, sem impedir uma outra forma de fazer. Dá pouco ou nenhum trabalho usar a convenção e dá de algum para muito trabalho configurar algo diferente, que ainda pode contar com convenções prontas e você nem precisa fazer, apenaa configurar o que quer usar daquela forma.

Dá para falar em uma desvantagem tangencial: o usuário perderá a chance de aprender algo, mas isso só se ele não for curioso, o conceito ajuda a tender ele ser preguiçoso, mas é uma questão de atitude.

Uma vantagem muito grande para o usuário é a curva de aprendizado muito mais baixa, inclusive se ela vai de um projeto para outro usando a mesma ferramenta tende a se adaptar ao novo projeto mais facilmente.

Claro que para o projeto pode ter a desvantagem do inexperiente ou preguiçoso escolher a convenção quando ela não é a melhor solução. Também pode complicar um pouco porque deixa implícito certas coisas e tudo parecer mágica demais, mas novamente, depende do usuário ser curioso.

Talvez a maior desvantagem não seja pelo conceito em si, mas porque em alguns casos ele tende a tornar o projeto inflexível demais e não atender tudo que precisa com configurações. É uma questão mais de como é feito do que uma premissa do conceito.

Para a ferramenta tem a desvantagem de ser um pouco mais complexa. Mas isso não é tão grave, ou nem é ruim porque uma alternativa é só ter a convenção que a deixa simples porém muito rígida e pouco útil pra muita gente. Dependendo do caso pode ser melhor ela apenas ter algo simples só com a convenção. Por outro lado fazer só do jeito que exige a configuração sem uma convenção dá praticamente o mesmo trabalho criando dificuldade para o usuário.

É comum essas ferramentas exigirem que o projeto seja criado dentro de certas premissas e até usar certos nomes ou estrutura de arquivos porque internamente ele espera assim. De uma certa forma isto pode reduzir a complexidade, então depende.

Se bem feito é muito vantajoso se a ferramenta demanda isto. Se mal feito a desvantagem não é dela, mas do mal uso dela, uma convenção que desagrada a maioria não é boa.

Em geral eles adotam o [princípio da menor surpresa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) (o que é mais provável que deve acontecer aqui).

Claro que pode haver abuso e ser mal feito e a convenção não adotar "as melhores práticas".

Isto está presente em ferramentas completas ou em coisas muito simples. Se você tiver uma função que faz algo com um argumento passado, mas se não passar nada ele ainda consegue fazer fazer algo útil adotando um valor padrão que teria sido passado, ou seja, há uma convenção de que aquele parâmetro tem um determinado valor em muitos casos, quando você passa o argumento está configurando a função para fazer algo de determinada forma.

Faz muito sentido em *frameworks* porque eles é que controlam sua aplicação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).